# Loss is nan, stopping training

Tags: pytorch, object-detection

I have a program as in the attached [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xaqnsqx0y8omz9j/VehicleDetection.py?dl=0).
The error is

```
Loss is nan, stopping training
{'loss_classifier': tensor(nan, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>), 'loss_box_reg': tensor(nan, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>), 'loss_mask': tensor(-2.1386e+22, device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<BinaryCrossEntropyWithLogitsBackward>), 'loss_objectness': tensor(0.7630, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<BinaryCrossEntropyWithLogitsBackward>), 'loss_rpn_box_reg': tensor(0.0572, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)}
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
```

I have suspect to data and printed all

```
labels, masks, boxes = self.readxml(annotation_path, img.size)     
print(labels)
print(masks.shape)
print(boxes)
```

I don't see any error in data.
What could be wrong?

```
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1]
(8, 576, 720)
[[101, 351, 124, 394], [96, 430, 126, 482], [110, 509, 141, 571], [472, 332, 515, 375], [541, 272, 585, 309], [487, 269, 529, 316], [379, 149, 418, 176], [441, 141, 508, 189]]
[3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1]
(8, 576, 720)
[[164, 402, 221, 465], [260, 390, 322, 487], [328, 325, 372, 372], [312, 287, 374, 322], [318, 218, 339, 236], [180, 257, 225, 289], [400, 246, 534, 326], [487, 189, 529, 229]]
[1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3]
(7, 576, 720)
[[127, 353, 233, 570], [308, 239, 333, 272], [270, 223, 294, 253], [232, 200, 264, 247], [323, 214, 344, 234], [366, 278, 439, 311], [583, 275, 656, 326]]
[3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4]
(15, 576, 720)
[[240, 173, 289, 220], [83, 190, 127, 233], [158, 243, 213, 305], [79, 300, 109, 359], [58, 403, 101, 478], [297, 348, 354, 403], [301, 222, 347, 270], [402, 297, 448, 361], [455, 324, 506, 390], [482, 445, 546, 500], [486, 480, 517, 508], [529, 419, 600, 483], [561, 46, 604, 82], [559, 138, 603, 189], [187, 308, 210, 345]]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3]
(18, 576, 720)
[[273, 158, 321, 202], [232, 101, 278, 143], [278, 84, 323, 132], [179, 67, 221, 101], [131, 23, 174, 71], [495, 456, 566, 524], [486, 507, 547, 570], [302, 308, 358, 369], [268, 400, 290, 431], [325, 360, 383, 417], [206, 475, 268, 540], [465, 196, 556, 318], [451, 168, 493, 211], [520, 103, 558, 139], [586, 34, 622, 69], [568, 134, 609, 184], [650, 135, 688, 224], [298, 142, 346, 184]]
/home/centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:3103: UserWarning: The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor changed in 1.6.0 to align with other frameworks/libraries, and now uses scale_factor directly, instead of relying on the computed output size. If you wish to restore the old behavior, please set recompute_scale_factor=True. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details. 
  warnings.warn("The default behavior for interpolate/upsample with float scale_factor changed "
[3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2]
(10, 576, 720)
[[295, 462, 346, 514], [347, 402, 401, 461], [386, 414, 433, 459], [483, 443, 507, 480], [441, 370, 485, 414], [408, 359, 453, 402], [452, 301, 500, 353], [493, 306, 537, 361], [491, 465, 541, 532], [486, 145, 573, 208]]
[3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]
(7, 576, 720)
[[193, 317, 242, 379], [262, 325, 290, 380], [319, 322, 370, 382], [518, 273, 597, 310], [313, 274, 384, 308], [477, 256, 489, 291], [458, 256, 474, 291]]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3]
(15, 576, 720)
[[136, 109, 182, 151], [184, 129, 228, 178], [85, 65, 129, 115], [541, 122, 575, 172], [230, 157, 305, 233], [300, 214, 349, 270], [344, 265, 385, 328], [89, 200, 137, 240], [109, 244, 131, 274], [84, 309, 114, 371], [187, 322, 248, 380], [58, 401, 103, 474], [557, 421, 636, 507], [554, 149, 598, 206], [633, 60, 676, 107]]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3]
(27, 576, 720)
[[598, 102, 642, 150], [570, 142, 608, 192], [131, 481, 199, 558], [84, 38, 121, 73], [125, 69, 167, 105], [191, 94, 259, 161], [152, 117, 199, 163], [211, 158, 262, 205], [299, 162, 347, 216], [295, 209, 346, 260], [333, 156, 379, 202], [378, 146, 430, 196], [399, 236, 450, 288], [442, 229, 495, 280], [352, 335, 413, 396], [287, 379, 316, 410], [363, 476, 429, 544], [483, 483, 565, 573], [514, 456, 591, 535], [519, 407, 591, 476], [490, 287, 522, 324], [585, 278, 618, 314], [642, 335, 675, 380], [434, 89, 478, 119], [526, 75, 574, 107], [340, 61, 391, 108], [129, 40, 172, 76]]
[3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]
(12, 576, 720)
[[95, 328, 149, 381], [15, 313, 92, 358], [211, 204, 266, 293], [138, 269, 203, 303], [363, 297, 420, 340], [303, 224, 328, 250], [273, 223, 298, 246], [530, 353, 597, 435], [514, 286, 555, 328], [461, 281, 496, 325], [491, 233, 517, 258], [428, 260, 443, 287]]
[3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
(16, 576, 720)
[[124, 100, 168, 142], [293, 208, 345, 262], [176, 124, 224, 173], [143, 247, 210, 333], [79, 311, 115, 385], [301, 305, 366, 370], [335, 256, 381, 315], [317, 430, 374, 483], [467, 347, 518, 408], [503, 455, 578, 519], [437, 152, 495, 269], [582, 450, 646, 524], [23, 482, 86, 571], [556, 150, 600, 203], [592, 109, 633, 157], [632, 60, 676, 106]]
Epoch: [0]  [  0/303]  eta: 0:09:51  lr: 0.000000  loss: -262.4095 (-262.4095)  loss_classifier: 1.5747 (1.5747)  loss_box_reg: 0.6368 (0.6368)  loss_mask: -264.8073 (-264.8073)  loss_objectness: 0.1623 (0.1623)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.0240 (0.0240)  time: 1.9534  data: 0.3372  max mem: 4226
[3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
(13, 576, 720)
[[191, 126, 229, 149], [230, 130, 272, 155], [282, 127, 342, 168], [344, 161, 386, 186], [397, 164, 442, 198], [453, 179, 493, 207], [92, 205, 125, 257], [103, 348, 129, 392], [259, 488, 321, 547], [426, 380, 472, 425], [570, 382, 621, 433], [530, 250, 567, 285], [568, 265, 614, 302]]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4]
(21, 576, 720)
[[325, 69, 371, 102], [133, 42, 171, 73], [100, 51, 136, 84], [138, 74, 181, 114], [195, 110, 237, 146], [265, 113, 310, 158], [193, 144, 238, 186], [246, 144, 290, 184], [329, 142, 382, 196], [300, 214, 320, 243], [331, 200, 385, 245], [385, 212, 405, 235], [162, 456, 230, 529], [372, 391, 401, 421], [425, 382, 495, 453], [503, 397, 565, 456], [555, 80, 646, 203], [520, 69, 563, 108], [637, 49, 682, 95], [549, 486, 626, 555], [374, 445, 398, 472]]
[3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
(11, 576, 720)
[[101, 387, 158, 451], [459, 303, 499, 351], [503, 242, 569, 333], [450, 245, 476, 275], [479, 220, 503, 246], [429, 257, 442, 291], [326, 234, 349, 260], [295, 227, 321, 250], [234, 277, 271, 315], [338, 211, 358, 231], [181, 256, 236, 291]]
[3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]
(15, 576, 720)
[[109, 105, 145, 133], [174, 122, 211, 148], [237, 125, 275, 157], [286, 134, 328, 166], [351, 150, 393, 177], [412, 139, 455, 184], [447, 173, 495, 205], [495, 156, 514, 178], [570, 190, 641, 253], [534, 277, 580, 317], [483, 310, 531, 363], [474, 444, 532, 504], [329, 461, 385, 515], [109, 416, 138, 472], [83, 196, 99, 222]]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3]
(8, 576, 720)
[[100, 313, 127, 367], [98, 452, 124, 501], [264, 479, 321, 538], [397, 405, 446, 451], [484, 356, 634, 487], [499, 297, 549, 348], [569, 255, 618, 292], [490, 159, 538, 185]]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3]
(11, 576, 720)
[[165, 367, 221, 423], [269, 340, 313, 395], [236, 289, 306, 332], [148, 290, 220, 327], [307, 275, 358, 314], [362, 281, 408, 315], [12, 306, 93, 349], [447, 250, 475, 295], [495, 251, 522, 292], [205, 261, 255, 290], [330, 208, 353, 226]]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 4]
(10, 576, 720)
[[248, 336, 297, 388], [321, 319, 363, 361], [211, 312, 253, 357], [302, 250, 332, 288], [352, 468, 426, 550], [429, 329, 474, 381], [457, 277, 493, 326], [443, 220, 472, 275], [498, 235, 522, 259], [335, 237, 347, 259]]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
(6, 576, 720)
[[165, 427, 240, 505], [373, 449, 457, 528], [336, 371, 395, 438], [250, 363, 312, 431], [219, 271, 296, 319], [250, 237, 279, 267]]
[3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 1, 3]
(14, 576, 720)
[[151, 118, 184, 142], [215, 126, 256, 154], [181, 108, 219, 135], [294, 122, 373, 173], [94, 270, 121, 316], [105, 370, 131, 416], [350, 457, 381, 489], [395, 410, 426, 444], [445, 356, 495, 403], [558, 263, 603, 299], [450, 179, 495, 206], [501, 180, 523, 203], [375, 127, 460, 186], [642, 235, 684, 265]]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1]
(14, 576, 720)
[[159, 388, 226, 460], [184, 342, 231, 394], [126, 290, 207, 329], [212, 285, 284, 333], [298, 277, 349, 313], [375, 274, 420, 309], [362, 250, 390, 280], [236, 237, 265, 270], [280, 229, 305, 257], [314, 204, 341, 242], [243, 196, 285, 236], [453, 236, 483, 290], [489, 250, 518, 286], [504, 191, 529, 233]]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3]
(10, 576, 720)
[[103, 363, 157, 422], [338, 341, 384, 391], [210, 259, 243, 296], [260, 248, 288, 282], [395, 288, 423, 336], [458, 269, 473, 305], [495, 342, 615, 499], [292, 230, 318, 262], [331, 214, 351, 232], [448, 239, 475, 270]]
[3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1, 3]
(11, 576, 720)
[[184, 336, 232, 387], [237, 241, 268, 275], [242, 182, 276, 239], [333, 217, 359, 237], [360, 261, 386, 292], [405, 252, 435, 291], [445, 252, 474, 287], [527, 290, 552, 333], [468, 211, 490, 238], [503, 178, 532, 231], [483, 251, 521, 286]]
[3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1]
(14, 576, 720)
[[269, 330, 314, 384], [201, 292, 246, 375], [354, 323, 375, 372], [272, 276, 311, 325], [325, 231, 351, 261], [288, 216, 308, 240], [259, 235, 286, 275], [227, 231, 255, 252], [315, 455, 354, 552], [588, 358, 647, 418], [510, 358, 570, 420], [415, 263, 480, 375], [510, 282, 548, 321], [500, 191, 533, 233]]
[3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3]
(11, 576, 720)
[[335, 311, 375, 372], [221, 254, 276, 288], [294, 236, 308, 261], [321, 241, 337, 273], [288, 191, 333, 230], [346, 208, 369, 226], [382, 287, 432, 333], [453, 326, 502, 394], [646, 269, 719, 312], [436, 258, 469, 291], [315, 277, 366, 316]]
[1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
(14, 576, 720)
[[280, 169, 401, 300], [607, 91, 647, 135], [565, 139, 606, 193], [173, 129, 219, 174], [522, 120, 555, 161], [452, 312, 500, 376], [330, 382, 392, 440], [178, 220, 230, 266], [94, 230, 148, 287], [66, 266, 99, 324], [70, 375, 108, 442], [469, 431, 542, 502], [601, 472, 687, 544], [639, 53, 679, 96]]
[3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3]
(10, 576, 720)
[[432, 168, 476, 197], [479, 183, 523, 221], [262, 106, 352, 166], [90, 250, 114, 287], [87, 408, 116, 465], [329, 457, 380, 508], [492, 445, 541, 499], [440, 356, 481, 399], [569, 283, 590, 309], [526, 254, 568, 291]]
[2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3]
(11, 576, 720)
[[144, 421, 221, 556], [259, 480, 339, 572], [337, 352, 389, 415], [268, 267, 316, 302], [130, 268, 182, 301], [194, 253, 214, 288], [312, 222, 338, 242], [436, 266, 456, 300], [493, 257, 523, 289], [372, 259, 395, 298], [406, 251, 434, 299]]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
(14, 576, 720)
[[259, 340, 302, 400], [106, 355, 158, 412], [88, 289, 172, 330], [175, 284, 246, 332], [36, 284, 76, 335], [279, 238, 311, 266], [352, 288, 393, 326], [396, 275, 431, 315], [360, 261, 391, 294], [494, 274, 572, 313], [620, 262, 694, 306], [397, 218, 420, 243], [297, 206, 319, 226], [580, 398, 661, 482]]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3]
(17, 576, 720)
[[273, 158, 321, 202], [337, 134, 382, 171], [278, 84, 323, 132], [179, 67, 221, 101], [131, 23, 174, 71], [495, 456, 566, 524], [486, 507, 547, 570], [239, 446, 295, 509], [316, 462, 380, 546], [325, 361, 383, 417], [381, 154, 489, 290], [446, 231, 491, 279], [598, 17, 632, 53], [653, 139, 676, 193], [487, 203, 503, 239], [298, 142, 346, 184], [677, 240, 720, 300]]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1]
(13, 576, 720)
[[181, 356, 227, 413], [260, 337, 303, 386], [202, 295, 281, 334], [381, 297, 437, 334], [478, 281, 539, 314], [475, 232, 499, 258], [447, 254, 474, 289], [395, 258, 422, 292], [502, 181, 531, 233], [461, 198, 475, 220], [387, 480, 469, 574], [226, 207, 258, 257], [300, 192, 351, 228]]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4]
(24, 576, 720)
[[293, 436, 347, 486], [328, 453, 375, 500], [342, 397, 391, 445], [370, 418, 422, 464], [399, 350, 450, 393], [421, 372, 470, 417], [450, 312, 489, 354], [470, 335, 512, 377], [100, 71, 141, 102], [127, 107, 162, 133], [205, 127, 248, 154], [225, 107, 262, 132], [73, 159, 96, 190], [89, 200, 112, 234], [87, 239, 109, 271], [85, 273, 110, 313], [85, 321, 113, 364], [90, 366, 104, 395], [638, 294, 666, 340], [585, 262, 613, 305], [586, 219, 629, 256], [497, 198, 546, 238], [391, 169, 427, 198], [524, 309, 550, 339]]
[1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3]
(13, 576, 720)
[[274, 166, 395, 297], [83, 318, 112, 375], [539, 417, 612, 485], [469, 348, 530, 419], [609, 91, 647, 135], [565, 139, 606, 193], [636, 487, 718, 560], [139, 106, 185, 151], [55, 420, 107, 495], [458, 472, 539, 559], [281, 391, 346, 462], [235, 285, 352, 398], [639, 53, 679, 96]]
[3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1]
(11, 576, 720)
[[265, 415, 327, 487], [329, 327, 375, 392], [267, 268, 350, 338], [178, 257, 231, 288], [222, 180, 258, 254], [349, 183, 383, 221], [404, 312, 459, 363], [533, 303, 577, 350], [435, 266, 508, 311], [623, 272, 691, 320], [396, 224, 436, 288]]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3]
(7, 576, 720)
[[246, 357, 301, 431], [106, 338, 153, 388], [212, 282, 278, 325], [228, 250, 268, 280], [271, 209, 319, 262], [440, 203, 482, 257], [445, 259, 471, 295]]
[1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3]
(13, 576, 720)
[[152, 65, 236, 114], [270, 120, 311, 145], [336, 127, 380, 174], [435, 184, 475, 210], [504, 266, 544, 302], [554, 270, 592, 309], [484, 320, 529, 361], [428, 357, 477, 414], [378, 366, 427, 410], [366, 421, 416, 467], [264, 466, 314, 513], [86, 330, 116, 391], [601, 225, 643, 254]]
[4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
(31, 576, 720)
[[45, 62, 59, 82], [150, 87, 188, 118], [212, 105, 252, 129], [157, 141, 202, 166], [210, 179, 256, 214], [268, 164, 315, 192], [284, 143, 327, 172], [317, 125, 361, 155], [361, 164, 397, 190], [375, 127, 416, 153], [421, 149, 464, 182], [414, 177, 455, 204], [299, 208, 346, 240], [382, 211, 427, 240], [431, 245, 489, 274], [505, 232, 559, 271], [518, 202, 559, 236], [549, 195, 594, 224], [504, 158, 550, 197], [587, 174, 631, 200], [604, 267, 657, 299], [470, 319, 518, 376], [432, 328, 473, 373], [432, 372, 477, 414], [385, 349, 434, 408], [384, 409, 432, 456], [326, 410, 382, 459], [309, 470, 363, 522], [207, 487, 274, 554], [84, 204, 108, 237], [467, 188, 509, 217]]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3]
(13, 576, 720)
[[167, 394, 235, 496], [372, 481, 453, 570], [332, 342, 382, 403], [257, 351, 297, 406], [238, 264, 278, 299], [328, 279, 407, 312], [386, 303, 460, 354], [473, 275, 550, 312], [291, 215, 317, 234], [326, 209, 346, 233], [440, 262, 451, 295], [399, 218, 421, 241], [467, 214, 486, 237]]
[3, 4, 1, 3]
(4, 576, 720)
[[404, 247, 427, 276], [458, 258, 472, 290], [482, 197, 518, 241], [487, 255, 513, 287]]
[3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
(13, 576, 720)
[[129, 353, 180, 409], [41, 402, 115, 507], [271, 305, 305, 348], [232, 282, 263, 323], [162, 254, 219, 293], [297, 260, 325, 289], [332, 228, 354, 251], [364, 467, 444, 551], [496, 365, 560, 443], [600, 354, 671, 422], [454, 268, 485, 303], [486, 251, 512, 284], [477, 204, 493, 225]]
[3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3]
(14, 576, 720)
[[250, 476, 325, 568], [308, 311, 324, 357], [164, 290, 235, 326], [56, 285, 90, 329], [156, 261, 209, 292], [222, 215, 271, 266], [291, 231, 315, 263], [322, 199, 354, 230], [447, 280, 481, 336], [496, 322, 540, 371], [546, 380, 617, 447], [473, 228, 508, 260], [405, 214, 426, 243], [331, 311, 370, 356]]
[2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
(9, 576, 720)
[[336, 382, 396, 477], [268, 294, 303, 331], [244, 272, 275, 305], [286, 242, 315, 270], [342, 219, 362, 243], [550, 371, 621, 450], [501, 333, 551, 391], [529, 304, 573, 353], [495, 254, 525, 301]]
[3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2]
(9, 576, 720)
[[130, 104, 164, 127], [175, 121, 212, 146], [294, 123, 374, 171], [377, 126, 458, 185], [450, 176, 492, 206], [621, 216, 644, 241], [570, 255, 615, 289], [456, 323, 493, 360], [107, 447, 137, 517]]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1]
(14, 576, 720)
[[117, 337, 168, 390], [172, 357, 223, 415], [154, 424, 218, 539], [259, 405, 320, 475], [339, 342, 382, 401], [398, 213, 448, 324], [355, 261, 387, 297], [268, 239, 295, 276], [248, 253, 263, 283], [312, 223, 338, 245], [488, 202, 534, 298], [467, 279, 483, 312], [284, 220, 306, 239], [238, 180, 277, 237]]
[3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
(12, 576, 720)
[[299, 219, 349, 272], [540, 124, 584, 174], [189, 136, 238, 185], [578, 87, 615, 128], [623, 27, 658, 71], [79, 71, 119, 107], [132, 104, 174, 145], [95, 299, 127, 360], [59, 426, 102, 494], [484, 149, 527, 196], [573, 133, 617, 185], [654, 78, 686, 140]]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
(14, 576, 720)
[[162, 418, 225, 495], [180, 357, 227, 412], [258, 337, 302, 385], [210, 251, 255, 284], [260, 237, 292, 268], [243, 197, 278, 238], [501, 183, 530, 233], [480, 216, 491, 239], [403, 217, 414, 241], [490, 256, 521, 289], [449, 253, 474, 289], [399, 261, 427, 292], [524, 292, 577, 336], [654, 277, 715, 314]]
[3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]
(13, 576, 720)
[[255, 446, 322, 525], [377, 429, 455, 530], [321, 383, 347, 455], [250, 268, 282, 299], [111, 266, 168, 300], [274, 238, 302, 274], [314, 229, 336, 251], [351, 206, 371, 223], [469, 270, 512, 337], [500, 321, 559, 395], [556, 326, 607, 390], [637, 277, 713, 319], [454, 219, 463, 238]]
[4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1]
(28, 576, 720)
[[237, 69, 256, 96], [259, 76, 305, 121], [314, 95, 377, 165], [268, 120, 311, 160], [253, 182, 304, 230], [281, 166, 336, 214], [317, 151, 361, 196], [508, 454, 588, 532], [204, 150, 249, 197], [106, 19, 145, 56], [119, 66, 158, 101], [280, 54, 322, 87], [110, 210, 155, 246], [273, 414, 329, 478], [319, 253, 382, 318], [462, 205, 512, 260], [411, 88, 462, 121], [477, 57, 542, 112], [614, 6, 647, 41], [585, 44, 619, 78], [541, 75, 579, 125], [579, 82, 621, 131], [528, 130, 574, 182], [557, 150, 599, 203], [662, 193, 700, 256], [617, 40, 652, 78], [632, 62, 672, 106], [384, 253, 543, 389]]
[3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
(8, 576, 720)
[[88, 201, 116, 229], [106, 258, 120, 288], [95, 331, 125, 377], [106, 429, 135, 483], [339, 465, 390, 517], [475, 334, 520, 379], [543, 282, 582, 315], [445, 176, 487, 205]]
[3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3]
(15, 576, 720)
[[175, 89, 217, 120], [229, 107, 258, 130], [264, 117, 299, 139], [307, 120, 346, 151], [364, 166, 405, 192], [431, 180, 473, 208], [507, 157, 547, 181], [60, 68, 95, 91], [90, 241, 113, 279], [87, 302, 114, 344], [85, 437, 114, 495], [351, 409, 395, 458], [446, 334, 494, 389], [520, 280, 569, 331], [617, 247, 665, 280]]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3]
(15, 576, 720)
[[393, 165, 430, 198], [342, 162, 380, 189], [270, 124, 308, 157], [233, 108, 270, 134], [294, 151, 334, 176], [196, 113, 233, 139], [127, 98, 163, 123], [99, 77, 133, 104], [411, 377, 463, 425], [507, 397, 576, 470], [538, 276, 583, 313], [80, 178, 105, 209], [97, 225, 110, 251], [85, 268, 108, 308], [323, 454, 378, 504]]
[3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3]
(12, 576, 720)
[[299, 219, 349, 272], [540, 124, 584, 174], [579, 85, 618, 126], [622, 27, 658, 72], [146, 107, 194, 154], [189, 230, 240, 273], [95, 230, 225, 370], [73, 284, 88, 318], [70, 340, 105, 409], [331, 386, 399, 451], [451, 328, 507, 393], [558, 436, 633, 507]]
Loss is nan, stopping training
{'loss_classifier': tensor(nan, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>), 'loss_box_reg': tensor(nan, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>), 'loss_mask': tensor(-2.1386e+22, device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<BinaryCrossEntropyWithLogitsBackward>), 'loss_objectness': tensor(0.7630, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<BinaryCrossEntropyWithLogitsBackward>), 'loss_rpn_box_reg': tensor(0.0572, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)}
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1


/home/centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3435: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

Comment: None of the linked code seems `to have a variable named `loss

Comment: Use an IDE ([PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) community edition is free, even for commercial use. Set breakpoints, step through your code, examine variables, and you will see your problem. Also, add exception handling & see what the exception tells you. That's the general approach to all such problems.

Comment: You should add your code (a minimal code example if possible) to your question.

Comment: If you are sure your data is ok then learning rate or weight decay, whatever, related to optimizer (depends on what you are using) is wrong.

Comment: @CynichniyBandera yes you are right it is hyper-parameters issue.